# Do we need/want a general "how do I SIM-unlock my phone" type question?

Tags: discussion, canonical-questions

This [bad answer to a valid question](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/5709/where-are-the-sim-lock-settings-stored-on-an-android-phone/13697#13697) (mods may have cleaned it up as a non-answer by the time you get there) prompted me to think that we already have a handful of questions about removing the SIM-lock, or region-lock on a phone (mainly in the [unlock](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/unlock) tag).

Of course these questions are [hardware specific](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/5709/where-are-the-sim-lock-settings-stored-on-an-android-phone), and in many ways not actually Android specific, but they do keep coming up every now and then.

Do we need a central "How do I remove the SIM lock on my Android phone?" question that can be wiki'd and explain the issues and either link to model specific answers, or list the ones that have come up so far in it?

Comment: For those of you who can't see deleted answers, the entire text of the "answer" was: "Pls my htc desire is locked up how will i unlock my simlock"

Comment: Did you post one?  We got [another](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/14649/orange-htc-hero-unlock-problems) unlocking question, so if you haven't then I will :)

Comment: @MatthewRead I've got a short draft of one at home, but suddenly got very busy and never got round to finishing and posting it. Will see if I can finish it off and post in the next couple of days.

Comment: No problem, I'll wait ;)

Answer (score 3):

Sounds like a good idea to me. Have at it!

Comment: Agreed, good thought GAThrawn.

Comment: I second the motion